# How to fix this error in python: Shape of passed values is (20, 32), indices imply (20, 38)

Tags: python

I am having an issue executing my code. The code aims to get a value for goals scored and conceded for each team based on playing statistics (held in a dataframe). The error message is: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20, 32), indices imply (20, 38)`. I don't entirely understand the code either as I got it from another resource and I am not too familiar with python, if it could be explained that would be awesome.

Getting goals scored:

```
 # Gets the goals scored agg arranged by teams and matchweek
def get_goals_scored(playing_stat):
# Create a dictionary with team names as keys
teams = {}
for i in playing_stat.groupby('HomeTeam').mean().T.columns:
    teams[i] = []

# the value corresponding to keys is a list containing the match location.
for i in range(len(playing_stat)):
    HTGS = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTHG']
    ATGS = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTAG']
    teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].HomeTeam].append(HTGS)
    teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].AwayTeam].append(ATGS)

# Create a dataframe for goals scored where rows are teams and cols are matchweek.
GoalsScored = pd.DataFrame(data=teams, index = [i for i in range(1,39)]).T
GoalsScored[0] = 0
# Aggregate to get uptil that point
for i in range(2,39):
    GoalsScored[i] = GoalsScored[i] + GoalsScored[i-1]
return GoalsScored
```

Getting goals conceded:

```
# Gets the goals conceded agg arranged by teams and matchweek
def get_goals_conceded(playing_stat):
# Create a dictionary with team names as keys
teams = {}
for i in playing_stat.groupby('HomeTeam').mean().T.columns:
    teams[i] = []

# the value corresponding to keys is a list containing the match location.
for i in range(len(playing_stat)):
    ATGC = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTHG']
    HTGC = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTAG']
    teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].HomeTeam].append(HTGC)
    teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].AwayTeam].append(ATGC)

# Create a dataframe for goals scored where rows are teams and cols are matchweek.
GoalsConceded = pd.DataFrame(data=teams, index = [i for i in range(1,39)]).T
GoalsConceded[0] = 0
# Aggregate to get uptil that point
for i in range(2,39):
    GoalsConceded[i] = GoalsConceded[i] + GoalsConceded[i-1]
return GoalsConceded
```

Comment: Is there a line number in the error msg?

Comment: There is an error in the line:
'GoalsScored = pd.DataFrame(data=teams, index = [i for i in range(1,39)]).T'
As well as:
'get_goals_scored(playing_statistics_1)'